# Meteor : getting data from collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

(It's my first app in meteor)
I have problem I can't get data from collection.
I'm going to make calendar.
I have collection with names of days and have array with this month days and mondey is 0 etc. 
In collection i have name and index and I'd like to display name of day if index is equal to number of day in array
I don't know if I do it good.
It's note all my app code and it's sorted in folders but i just copied code where I need help

```
    <template name="calendar">

            {{#each months}}
            <span>{{name}}</li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>    
        {{days}}
        <div class="calendar">
            <ul>            
                {{#each daysofweek}}
                <li>
                    {{index}}
                </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
            {{#each generateCalendar}}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        {{#each this}}
                        <li>
                            {{day}}: {{dayOfWeek}}
                        </li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {{/each}}
        </div>    
        <!--    <button class="remove">click</button>-->
    </template>


db = new Array;
db['dayoftheweek'] = new Mongo.Collection('dayoftheweek');
db['months'] = new Mongo.Collection('months');
Template.calendar.helpers({
'daysofweek': function () {        
        return db['dayoftheweek'].find();        
    },
    'generateCalendar': function () {
        var tab = [];
        var daysInMonth = Session.get('currentMonthDays');
        var fDay = Session.get('currentMonthFDay');
        for (var i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            tab[i] = {day: i, dayOfWeek: fDay};
            if (fDay === 6) {
                fDay = 0;
            } else {
                fDay++;
            }
        }
        var weeks = [];
        var i = 0;
        while (tab.length > 0) {
            if (i === 0) {
                weeks[i] = tab.splice(0, (8 - Session.get('currentMonthFDay')));
                i++;
            } else {
                weeks[i] = tab.splice(0, 7);
                i++;
            }
        }        
        return weeks;
    }

});
Meteor.methods({
    'removeFromDb': function(selected, dbname){        
        db[dbname].remove(selected);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your problem right but I think that you are missing that `collection.find()` method returns a cursor. So if you want to fetch the data you need to call `cursor.fetch()` method which will return you an array with the data. 

 Check the docs of the find method: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find 
 Fetch method docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch

To print all names of objects from the array you'll need a loop: 
`var days = db['dayoftheweek'].find().fetch();
for(var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
   console.log(days[i].name);
}`

Comment: when I use 
    console.log(db['dayoftheweek'].find().fetch());
it return me array of Objects how can i get data from this objects ?

Comment: Every object is a record from your collection. If your "dayoftheweek" collection has a column that is called "name" you can call `object.name`.

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example because the code is not well formatted in the comments.

Comment: i solved it but could you check whole my code and say something about it ?
'daysofweek': function (dayOfWeek) {        
        return db['dayoftheweek'].find().fetch()[dayOfWeek].name;        
    }
<li>
                        {{day}}: {{daysofweek dayOfWeek}}
                    </li>

Comment: `daysofweek` method would work pretty fine but you can make a few improvements. You can use the method to return the array with ALL days of week names not just a single one. And you can use this array to show the name of the day you need. That would be better because you won't make a request which gets all the data from the `daysofweek` collection just to get one name as it is now. The other possible way to improve your code is to add a selector to the `find()` function and to get the data for the needed day of week only. Using `findOne()` function with a selector would be pretty fine too.